# Is my activity being leaked - and is it the ActionBar that's doing it?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I have an Activity named PhotoSelectorActivity.  It inherits from a BaseActivity that looks like this:

```
public class BaseActivity
extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
        "onCreate("+Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))+")");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(null);
    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
        "onDestroy("+Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))+")");
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            return onNavigateUp(item);
        case R.id.menu_item_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
protected ActionBar setupActionBar(boolean enableBackButton) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(enableBackButton);
    }
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The purpose of this BaseActivity is to provide the same menu and actionbar to each one of my activities.  You'll notice the `getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(null)` in the `onDestroy()` method, that's there to try and combat the problem that I may be having.

When i get an orientation change event, i notice in DDMS that i end up with 2 instances of my activity.  One of them may be leaking, but I'm not certain.  Here's a screen shot from DDMS:

[image: DDMS screenshot of offending extra activity]

So the object at the top is the Activity in question: PhotoSelectorActivity.  The instance shown here is the previous instance (`onDestroy()` has already been called on it). Yet it remains in memory even after a forced GC via DDMS.

Another bit of information is that this only seems to happen after using a dialog.  That is, when the Activity is initially displayed and before the user performs and action I can do back to back orientation changes without the # of activities climbing above 1.  After I've used the following dialog i seem to get the extra Activity in memory:

```
public class PhotoSourceDialog
extends DialogFragment
implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

public static interface PhotoSourceDialogListener {
    void onPhotoSourceSelected(String result);
}

private PhotoSourceDialogListener listener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (!PhotoSourceDialogListener.class.isInstance(activity)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
            "Activity must implement PhotoSourceDialogListener");
    }
    listener = PhotoSourceDialogListener.class.cast(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    listener = null;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTitle(R.string.photo_source)
        .setItems(R.array.photo_sources, this).create();
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    String choice = getResources().getStringArray(
        R.array.photo_sources)[which];
    if (listener!=null) {
        listener.onPhotoSourceSelected(choice);
    }
}

}
```

and to invoke it i do this in my activity:

```
PhotoSourceDialog dialog = new PhotoSourceDialog();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), PhotoSourceDialog.class.getName());
```

So my question is this: Should I be worried?  Is this just something that is hanging around for a bit but will eventually be GCd?  I would think that if there was a leak it would grow higher than 2.

Comment: Opened a bug here as well: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=setCustomView&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=60067

Comment: I think I might be overreacting, after letting the APP sit for a bit the extra activity seems to have been GCed - but why did it take so long and why was the ActionMenuItem holding onto it for so long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this question.  Someone at google has responded with the following:

> OK, in that case then it's not an AppCompat bug since the standard
>   Action Bar implementation is used on ICS+.
>
> Looking at that MAT screenshot, the framework's ActionMenuItemView is
>   being referenced from a clipboard event which is being finalized,
>   hence about to be GC'd. The LayoutInflater is *probably* the
>   LayoutInflater that the Activity keeps itself (getLayoutInflater()).